# iPhone SDK: Memory leak on picker

Tags: iphone

I have created a picker for my users to pick from a list of countries. The problem is that repeated opening and closing of the picker is resulting in “EXC_BAD_ACCESS” error. I suspect it might be a memory leak but I am not sure. I was hoping someone could shed some insight into why this might be happening?

```
//data source for UIPicker 
NSArray *arrayCountryChoices;



arrayCountryChoices = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"TK=TOKELAU",
                           @"TJ=TAJIKISTAN",
                           @"TH=THAILAND",
                           @"TG=TOGO",
                           @"TF=FRENCH SOUTHERN TERRITORIES",
                           @"GY=GUYANA",
                           @"TD=CHAD", nil];

//opening the picker
        CountryViewController *countryVC = [[CountryViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CountryView" bundle:nil];
        countryVC.delegate = self;      
        [self presentModalViewController:countryVC animated:YES];       
        [countryVC release];    

//here is where I grab the data
    //close country selector
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    //parse out code
    NSString *strCode = [chosenCountry substringToIndex:2];

    //set the gui
    txtCountry.text = strCode;
```

I think it may be because I am trying to release the Country Selector before the delegate has a chance to get its data? Also I am wondring if I should not release the picker until the screen that calls it is released.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What line of code is generating the EXC_BAD_ACCESS? That's important information.

Answer (score 0):

Releasing the view after you've added it as a modal view is not a problem because it's being held in the viewController's modalViewController property. However, when you dismiss the modal view it does die so this message:

```
 NSString *strCode = [chosenCountry substringToIndex:2];
```

...has no target/receiver. You should simply move this line to the line before you dismiss the modalView so that the `chosenCountry` object is still alive when the message is sent.

Comment: I did not mention I have more than one modal view controller being called from this single view. Therefore, I don't think I can rely on the mainViews modalViewController property.

Comment: The modalViewController property just holds whatever modal view is being used at the moment. You don't "rely on" it it just happens as part of the view controllers normal function. My point was that once you dismiss a modal view the controller removes it from its own modalViewController property and the modal view then deallocates. Therefore, you need to extract any information from the view before you dismiss it.

Comment: The problem was that I was dismissing the modal controller prior to the call back being invoked. It is significant that I have more than one modal controller for this view controller. In that case, the first suggested answer does not apply. In particular this part, "Releasing the view after you've added it as a modal view is not a problem because it's being held in the viewController's modalViewController property". In this situation, I cannot rely on that premise to handle my memory management for me. As soon as I stopped releasing the modal view controller after I created it, all is good.

Comment: You've got more than one modal view active at the same time?